# Using map (purrr) to iterate over two vectors in R

Tags: r, function, purrr

I am trying to plot maps for three different dependent variables (each plotted separately), over multiple metro areas. To do this, I am trying to do 2 nested maps. I start by doing it just over the 3 different variables foe one metro area - defining the function and running it through map and it works. The code for this part is below:

```
plot_fun <- function(x){
  base_plot_2015$`14460` +
  data_2015 %>% subset(met2013 == 14460) %>% subset(onetsoccode == "151021") %>% 
    geom_sf(mapping = aes_string(fill = x)) +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma") 
}

expl <- names(data_2015)[17:19]
expl <- set_names(expl)

plot_Boston <- map(expl, ~plot_fun(.x))
```

This gives me a list of 3 maps and so far so good. (Please note that the base_plot is a list containing maps of each of the metro areas saved as the metro area id, which is stored as double).

Next, I want to do the same, but also iterate it over different metro codes. I try doing this by defining the following function:

```
plot_fun <- function(x,y){
  base_plot_2015$`y` +
    data_2015 %>% subset(met2013 == y) %>% subset(onetsoccode == "151021") %>% 
    geom_sf(mapping = aes_string(fill = x)) +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma") 
}
```

The idea is to map it over a vector of metro areas (y) for each dependent variable to be plotted(x). However, before I do that, I can't get this function to work. When I run this function using `plot_fun("work_home", 14460)`, I get the following error:

**Error in base_plot_2015$y + data_2015 %>% subset(met2013 == y) %>% subset(onetsoccode ==  : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator**

Would someone be kind enough to point out what I am doing wrong here?

Also, to do the nested map, does the code `map(met, ~map(expl, ~plot_fun, y=.x))` (where met is a vector of metro area codes) make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: When you subsetting your base_plot list, you need to use the `[[` operator instead of `$`

In your second version, the function sees it as "y" a string, not the variable `y`. Since, presumably, there is no metro code "y", `NULL` is returned. The binary operator is `+` and `NULL` is non-numeric. Here's a simplified example of what's happening:

```
base_data <- list(
  a = letters,
  b = LETTERS,
  c = rnorm(100)
)

getMyData <- function(y){
  base_data$`x`
} 

getMyData("a")
#> NULL

base_data$x <- "QSBjbHVlIHBlcmhhcHM="

val <- getMyData("a") %>% print()
#> [1] "QSBjbHVlIHBlcmhhcHM="

base64enc::base64decode(val) %>% rawToChar()
#> [1] "A clue perhaps"
```

If you change your function to use the `[[` operator, you can use the string value in the variable `y` to subset:

```
actuallyGetMyData <- function(x){
  base_data[[x]]
}

actuallyGetMyData("a")[1:10]
#> [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

**EDIT**: Regarding the mapping over the permutations (because it's hard to read code in comments)

the call `map(expl, ~plot_fun)` creates an anonymous function that returns the function `plot_fun`. You either need to drop the anonymous function

```
map(met, ~map(expl, plot_fun, y=.x))
```

or call the function

```
map(met, ~map(expl, ~plot_fun(.x, .y), .y=.x))
```

I find the nested maps a little hard to read (.x becoming .y and what not) so alternatively you could just first enumerate all the combinations and then map over those

```
plotVars <- expand.grid(expl, met)
plot_final <- map2(plotVars[[1]], plotsVars[[2]],  plot_fun) %>% 
  set_names(paste(plotVars[[1]], plotVars[[2]], sep = "_"))
```

Note that your `plot_final` list will no longer be nested though.

Comment: This is very useful, thank you! I still cannot however map this function over the two layers, that is when I run `plot_final <- map(met, ~map(expl, ~plot_fun,.y=.x))`, I end up with a big list of 10 (one for each metro area), but each metro area has a list of 3 functions, instead of the 3 plots that should be there.

Comment: So you're mixing notation - `~plot_fun` creates an anonymous function that returns the function `plot_fun` (hence your list of functions). You want either just `plot_fun` or make the call with `~plot_fun(.x, .y)` 

Full line assignment you want either:
`plot_final <- map(met, ~map(expl, plot_fun, y=.x))` or
`plot_final <- map(met, ~map(expl, ~plot_fun(.x, .y), .y=.x))`

Comment: Frankly I find the nested maps a little hard to read so what you could alternatively do is enumerate all the combinations and the just map through those (result would no longer be a nested list) `plotVars <- expand.grid(expl, met)
plot_final3 <- map2(plotVars[[1]], plotsVars[[2]],  plot_fun) %>% 
  set_names(paste(plotVars[[1]], plotVars[[2]], sep = "_"))
`

Comment: Ah, that's what I was doing wrong. This makes so much sense. Thank you so much!